# Automatic re-naming of bind variable in Execute Anonymous debug log - why did/does this happen?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a simple execute anon script, which outputs something unexpected.

**Execute anon script**

```
Id accountId = '0012500000EJiaG';  
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:accountId]; 
for(Account a : accountList){
    System.debug('Hi ' + a);
    System.debug('Size = ' + accountList.size());
}
```

I notice that one of the lines in the debug log is:

```
18:15:17.090 (90279991)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[3]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
```

So the debug log auto-renamed the bind variable 'accountId' to 'tmpVar1'.

Questions:

1) Why did this auto-renaming of the variable happen?

2) Also, in my logs, I didn't get any System.debug messages and I would expect one (as there is an Account with that Id in my org). Any idea why?

Thanks,